# Crashlytics working but missing certain crash types?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, crash-reports, unhandled-exception, google-fabric

I use Fabric/Crashlytics, and it is working well - I see crash reports and logged non-fatal exceptions as I expect, but I will occasionally see a substantial number of crashes in Xcode/Window/Organizer/Crashes that have no corresponding Crashlytics crash reports, and this is even with only seeing reports in Xcode from users that have opted in to sharing.

Are there classes of crashes/uncaught exceptions that Crashlytics does not catch?  For instance, one particular crash captured by Apple but not by Crashlytics was caused by an infinite recursive loop that happened in a very specific use case.  Is this type of problem not captured by Crashlytics?  Is this documented somewhere?

To be clear, this is not a question about Crashlytics setup, missing DSYM files, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Are these crashes when Xcode is attached? Crashlytics only reports when Xcode is not attached to the device or simulator.

Comment: Nope, these are crashes in the production app out in the wild.